# Probability of choose a number, that is prime and with two digits

Tags: probability

I have this statement:

> What is the probability that when choosing a positive number of two
>   digits, this is a prime and ends in 3?

Basically, my development was:

Here i have $90 - 9$ positive numbers, with two digits.

So the total cases are $90$.

Now, the cases of the numbers that ends in $3$ are every tens (13, 23, 33, etc), here i have 9 tens. Therefore, are $9/90$ numbers that ends in $3$

Between $10-99$ exist $21 $ primes, that are:

$11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97$

So, are $21/90$ primes.

The intersection of these events will be: $(21/90) * (9/90) = 7/300$

But the answer is wrong.

I know that is easy, get all numbers that ends in $3$ $(13, 23, 33, 43...)$ and see what are primes. In fact, i have the correct answer too.

However, i want to know why my development is wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The product-formula for intersection does only hand if your events are independent, which is not true here. So what is wrong is the line

> the intersection of these events will be: (21/99) * (9/90)

Comment: I must use conditional probability?

Comment: Yes, you _can_: if A and B are two events such that $\mathbf P(B) \neq 0$, then $\mathbf P(A | B)$ is (by definition) equal to $\frac{\mathbf P(A \cap B)}{\mathbf P(B)}$, thus $\mathbf P(A \cap B) = \mathbf P(A |B) \mathbf P(B)$. But it is _clearly_ not the good approach to compute the probability that an uniformly drawn two-digit number is a prime ending by three!

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your approach is that ending in the chances of the number ending in $3$ and being prime are not independent.  Therefore, you cannot use the multiplication formula for probabilities.  Simply look at the list  of primes and find how many end in a 3.  That number divided by 90 is your answer.

Comment: So if are dependent, i should use conditional probability?

Comment: @Mattiu, yes, that's one way to handle it.